# Matlab legend from cell for plot created with for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, legend, cell-array

I want to create a legend in Matlab that uses the cell called labels in the dummy code below. I've read the handbook and posts in this forum, which suggest to use legend(labels{:}) - yet it still shows only the last legend entry. legend('show') shows all the entries but not with the correct names as defined in labels. What did I get wrong?

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
format long;

data = cell(4,2);
for number = 1:2
     data{1,number} = [1 3 5];
     data{2,number} = [4 2 9];
     data{3,number} = [2 7 3];
     data{4,number} = [7 4 2];
end

labels = cell(4,2);
for number = 1:2
    labels{1,number} = {strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 1')};
    labels{2,number} = {strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 2')};
    labels{3,number} = {strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 3')};
    labels{4,number} = {strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 4')};
end

x = 1:3;

figure;
hold on;
for i = 1:numel(data)
   plot(x, data{i},'-o','LineWidth',1.1);
end
hold off;
   legend(labels{:});
%    legend('show');
   xlim([0.5 3+0.5]);
   ylim([0 10]);
   set(gca, 'xTick', 1:3, 'yTick', 0:1:10 );
   ytickformat('percentage');
   xlabel('Scenarios');
```

Comment: Your labels variable is a 4x2 cell array. What kind of legend do you expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
    labels{1,number} = strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 1');
    labels{2,number} = strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 2');
    labels{3,number} = strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 3');
    labels{4,number} = strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 4');
```

Because otherwise you are creating cell inside cell and they must be string inside cell.

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
format long;

data = cell(4,2);
for number = 1:2
     data{1,number} = [1 3 5];
     data{2,number} = [4 2 9];
     data{3,number} = [2 7 3];
     data{4,number} = [7 4 2];
end

labels = cell(4,2);
for number = 1:2
    labels{1,number} = strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 1');
    labels{2,number} = strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 2');
    labels{3,number} = strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 3');
    labels{4,number} = strcat(string(number), ': legend entry 4');
end

x = 1:3;

figure;
hold on;
for i = 1:numel(data)
   plot(x, data{i},'-o','LineWidth',1.1);
end
hold off;
   legend(labels{:});
%    legend('show');
   xlim([0.5 3+0.5]);
   ylim([0 10]);
   set(gca, 'xTick', 1:3, 'yTick', 0:1:10 );
   ytickformat('percentage');
   xlabel('Scenarios');
```

**Now is correct.**

> Figure Output:

[image]